# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Tags: request, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to post a message on a Facebook user's profile using Facebook API. It happens sometimes after authentication to send a message but the second time it always returns this error (just to mention that I use this for asp.net webapplication):

```
An error occurred:The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Facebook.FacebookAPI.MakeRequest(Uri url, HttpVerb httpVerb, Dictionary`2 args) in \wwwroot\App_Code\FacebookAPI.cs:line 185 at Facebook.FacebookAPI.Call(String relativePath, HttpVerb httpVerb, Dictionary`2 args) in \wwwroot\App_Code\FacebookAPI.cs:line 134 at Facebook.FacebookAPI.Post(String relativePath, Dictionary`2 args) in \wwwroot\App_Code\FacebookAPI.cs:line 107 at Views_Publish_to_facebook.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \wwwroot\Views\MarketingTool\Publish_to_facebook.aspx.cs:line 90
```

What could I do?
this is the login button

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink='true' perms='read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' onlogin='window.location.reload()'>
</fb:login-button>
```

Facebook C# SDK

This is my Facebook API code.

```
/*
* Copyright 2010 Facebook, Inc.
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
* not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
* a copy of the License at
* 
*  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
* WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
* License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
* under the License.
*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Facebook
{
    enum HttpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        DELETE
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper around the Facebook Graph API. 
    /// </summary>
    public class FacebookAPI
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The access token used to authenticate API calls.
        /// </summary>
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of the API, with public access only.
        /// </summary>
        public FacebookAPI()
            : this(null) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of the API, using the given token to
        /// authenticate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">The access token used for
        /// authentication</param>
        public FacebookAPI(string token)
        {
            AccessToken = token;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a Facebook Graph API GET request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="relativePath">The path for the call,
        /// e.g. /username</param>
        public JSONObject Get(string relativePath)
        {
            return Call(relativePath, HttpVerb.GET, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a Facebook Graph API GET request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="relativePath">The path for the call,
        /// e.g. /username</param>
        /// <param name="args">A dictionary of key/value pairs that
        /// will get passed as query arguments.</param>
        //public JSONObject Get(string relativePath,
        //                      Dictionary<string, string> args)
        public JSONObject Get(string relativePath,
                              Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            return Call(relativePath, HttpVerb.GET, args);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a Facebook Graph API DELETE request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="relativePath">The path for the call,
        /// e.g. /username</param>
        public JSONObject Delete(string relativePath)
        {
            return Call(relativePath, HttpVerb.DELETE, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a Facebook Graph API POST request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="relativePath">The path for the call,
        /// e.g. /username</param>
        /// <param name="args">A dictionary of key/value pairs that
        /// will get passed as query arguments. These determine
        /// what will get set in the graph API.</param>
        public JSONObject Post(string relativePath,
                               Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            return Call(relativePath, HttpVerb.POST, args);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a Facebook Graph API Call.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="relativePath">The path for the call, 
        /// e.g. /username</param>
        /// <param name="httpVerb">The HTTP verb to use, e.g.
        /// GET, POST, DELETE</param>
        /// <param name="args">A dictionary of key/value pairs that
        /// will get passed as query arguments.</param>
        private JSONObject Call(string relativePath,
                                HttpVerb httpVerb,
                                Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            Uri baseURL = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com");
            //relativePath = "/me";
            Uri url = new Uri(baseURL, relativePath);
            if (args == null)
            {
                args = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessToken))
            {
                args["access_token"] = AccessToken;
            }
            JSONObject obj = JSONObject.CreateFromString(MakeRequest(url,
                                                                     httpVerb,
                                                                     args));
            if (obj.IsDictionary && obj.Dictionary.ContainsKey("error"))
            {
                throw new FacebookAPIException(obj.Dictionary["error"]
                                                  .Dictionary["type"]
                                                  .String,
                                               obj.Dictionary["error"]
                                                  .Dictionary["message"]
                                                  .String + " -> " + url + " " + httpVerb + " " + args);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Make an HTTP request, with the given query args
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The URL of the request</param>
        /// <param name="verb">The HTTP verb to use</param>
        /// <param name="args">Dictionary of key/value pairs that represents
        /// the key/value pairs for the request</param>
        private string MakeRequest(Uri url, HttpVerb httpVerb,
                                   Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            if (args != null && args.Keys.Count > 0 && httpVerb == HttpVerb.GET)
            {
                url = new Uri(url.ToString() + EncodeDictionary(args, true));
            }
            //throw new Exception(url.AbsoluteUri +  " ---- " + url.AbsolutePath);

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            request.Method = httpVerb.ToString();

            if (httpVerb == HttpVerb.POST)
            {
                string postData = EncodeDictionary(args, false);

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] postDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            try
            {
                //using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

                //throw new Exception(response.ResponseUri + " tra " + response.Server);
                {
                    StreamReader reader
                        = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                throw new FacebookAPIException("Server Error", e.Message + " resp: " + request.GetResponse() + " " + response.ResponseUri + " tra " + response.Server);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encode a dictionary of key/value pairs as an HTTP query string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dict">The dictionary to encode</param>
        /// <param name="questionMark">Whether or not to start it
        /// with a question mark (for GET requests)</param>
        private string EncodeDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict,
                                        bool questionMark)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (questionMark)
            {
                sb.Append("?");
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
            {
                sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key));
                sb.Append("=");
                //NOTE: This line causes problems with access_token. The url encoding messes up the access_token, so for now I'm just adding it directly
                //if the key == "access_token"
                //sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value));
                if (kvp.Key.ToLower() == "access_token")
                {
                    sb.Append(kvp.Value);
                    //sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(kvp.Value)));
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value));
                }

                sb.Append("&");
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // Remove trailing &
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to look at another Facebook C# SDK - http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com